# Typing/Entering a value into a text field - Python 2.7

Tags: excel, python-2.7, tkinter, xlrd

I am reading cell values from an excel sheet using xlrd, clicking into a text box, and I want to the enter the excel values into that text box.  Here's the bit of my code that matters;

```
#move the cursor to a location
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
win32api.SetCursorPos((200,100))

#right click 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
print "Click."    

#enter the room name(HERE'S WHERE I NEED HELP)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

myString = (sheet.cell(0,0).value)
print myString
```

I know 'print myString' will just print it in the shell, but I've left it for clarification purposes.
Any suggestions on how to enter the value into the box?

P.S. After my script double clicks, the text box appears, and the text in it is highlighted and ready for typing to begin.

Thanks,
Mason

Comment: Mason can you help a little bit with your question.  Are you having trouble getting a value for myString?  Or is that not a problem.  You are solely having an issue with a 'Text Box'.  where is the text box, what initiates it?

Comment: EoinS, I ended up using tkinter and managed to find a solution. But thank you for reaching out!

Comment: Hey great.  Post an answer to your own question and share that knowlege!  Thanks for responding

Comment: SOLUTION:(using pyperclip) (assign cell value as string to a variable and add it to the clipboard. Allows me to use keyboard strokes to paste it in the box I want it in.) Here's what I did;  room = str(sheet.cell(i+1,0).value)   
    addToClipBoard(room)      pressHoldRelease('ctrl','v')